# Which javascript events can trigger a popup without being blocked?

Tags: javascript, browser, dom-events

I'd like to trigger a popup dialog when a user hits enter in a search box that allows them to give more details before searching. Of course, this works fine when they click on the search button. The popup tends to get blocked when I try to use a keypress handler to trigger the popup when the user hits the enter key.

Which Javascript events can safely trigger a popup? Is onclick the only one or is there a key handling event (or some other way I haven't thought of)?

Here's an example:

```
$('input.search').keypress(function(event){
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        // trigger popup
    }
});
```

This does trigger a popup, but popup blockers will catch it most of the time.

Comment: Can you show what you are doing now?

Comment: You can bind any event handler to any event. There are no restrictions. You can use any event to trigger the popup.

Answer (score 1):

Popup blockers today tend to block everything but direct mouse actions. Perhaps you should consider using ajax to load the preview instead of a popup, then overlaying the ajax result on the page.

Comment: That'd be best, probably, but the popup is triggered by the Facebook Connect library I'm using, so there's not much of a way around using a popup.